# apache drill 1.13.0 (embedded mode) cannot access web console and command line

Tags: apache-drill

I am using apache-drill-1.13.0 on Windows 7, embedded mode. I get "no current connection" errors when sending any queries. Also, drill web console which should be working on localhost:8047 is not working.
I also used jps, and used localhost:12080

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8eVC.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhKgO.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVJlP.png
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYsuF.png

   Logs from my drill

   2018-06-29 13:09:21,357 [main] INFO  o.a.drill.common.config.DrillConfig - Configuration and plugin file(s) identified in 106ms.
       Base Configuration:
           - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-common-1.13.0.jar!/drill-default.conf

   ```
   Intermediate Configuration and Plugin files, in order of precedence:
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-storage-kafka-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-opentsdb-storage-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-hive-exec-shaded-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-java-exec-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-storage-hbase-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-kudu-storage-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-logical-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-jdbc-storage-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-mongo-storage-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-gis-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-memory-base-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-common-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf
       - jar:file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/jars/drill-storage-hive-core-1.13.0.jar!/drill-module.conf

   Override File: file:/C:/apache-drill-1.13.0/conf/drill-override.conf
   Overridden Properties:
       -user = 
       -password = 
       -zk = local


   2018-06-29 13:09:21,673 [main] WARN  o.a.drill.exec.util.GuavaPatcher - Unable to patch Guava classes.
   javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/google/common/base/Stopwatch"
       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1099) ~[javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar:na]
       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1042) ~[javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar:na]
       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1000) ~[javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar:na]
       at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1140) ~[javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar:na]
       at org.apache.drill.exec.util.GuavaPatcher.patchStopwatch(GuavaPatcher.java:66) ~[drill-java-exec-1.13.0.jar:1.13.0]
       at org.apache.drill.exec.util.GuavaPatcher.patch(GuavaPatcher.java:36) ~[drill-java-exec-1.13.0.jar:1.13.0]
       at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.<clinit>(Drillbit.java:69) [drill-java-exec-1.13.0.jar:1.13.0]
       at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:134) [drill-jdbc-1.13.0.jar:1.13.0]
       at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:73) [drill-jdbc-1.13.0.jar:1.13.0]
       at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69) [drill-jdbc-1.13.0.jar:1.13.0]
       at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:138) [avatica-1.10.0.jar:1.10.0]
       at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72) [drill-jdbc-1.13.0.jar:1.13.0]
       at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:168) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:214) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1083) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1015) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:742) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:528) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:596) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:375) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
       at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:268) [sqlline-1.1.9-drill-r7.jar:na]
   Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/google/common/base/Stopwatch"
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass2(ClassPool.java:1112) ~[javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar:na]
       at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1093) ~[javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar:na]
       ... 25 common frames omitted
   ```

Comment: I assume you followed these steps:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-windows/
If so, you have some error. Please find it in the logs dir and share it here.
Most likely it is a deserialization error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like from jps output that Drillbit processes are not running hence error for sqlline and localhost:8047 is expected. Can you please share more information from logs why Drillbit itself is not up and running ?